# How to convert a dictionary of strings into a block of text with python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary full of string-valued k-v pairs, and I want each to be separated by `==>`& then printed to a newline.

I use an array to mediate the transformation, which seems unnecessary & inelegant. **I'd like to do this in 1 line if possible.**

Here's what I have:

```
foo_dict = {
    'a' : '1',
    'b' : '2',
    'c' : '3',
    }
foo_list = []
for k, v in foo_dict.items():
    foo_list.append('{} ==> {}'.format(k, v))
foo_text = '\n'.join(foo_list)
```

this will print:

```
b ==> 2
c ==> 3
a ==> 1
```

the order doesn't matter (otherwise I'd just use `OrderedDict`.) What matters is that all k-v pairs get printed in the correct format.

Comment: ```...1 line if possible``` - why?

Comment: @wwii for to read better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following one-liner will do:

```
foo_text = '\n'.join('{} ==> {}'.format(*t) for t in foo_dict.items())
```

Or we can use a `starmap(..)`:

```
from itertools import starmap

foo_text = '\n'.join(starmap('{} ==> {}'.format,foo_dict.items()))
```

Both generate:

```
>>> '\n'.join('{} ==> {}'.format(*t) for t in foo_dict.items())
'b ==> 2\na ==> 1\nc ==> 3'
>>> '\n'.join(starmap('{} ==> {}'.format,foo_dict.items()))
'b ==> 2\na ==> 1\nc ==> 3'
```

`str.join` simply accepts any type of *iterable* so we can use a generator, or a list. We can also boost the former a bit by using list comprehension:

```
foo_text = '\n'.join(['{} ==> {}'.format(*t) for t in foo_dict.items()])
```

This being said note that simply writing one-liners because it is possible is not a good reason. You should always go for readability (given it does not alter the time complexity or has a significant impact on efficiency). In this case this is probably not a problem. But cryptical one-liners are rather *un-Pythonic*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be a one-liner, you write a list comprehension and join the string elements with `\n`:

```
print('\n'.join(["{} ==> {}".format(k, foo_dict[k]) for k in foo_dict]))
```

Answer (score 2):

While other answers here have provided good ways of formatting your regular dictionary, if you have many cases where you need this functionality, you may want to consider creating a custom dictionary object by inheriting from `collections.UserDict`, and overriding its default `__repr__()`:

```
>>> from collections import UserDict
>>> 
>>> class custom_dict(UserDict):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '\n'.join('{} ==> {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.data.items())
... 
>>> foo_dict = {
...     'a' : '1',
...     'b' : '2',
...     'c' : '3',
...     }
>>> 
>>> new_dict = custom_dict(foo_dict)
>>> new_dict
a ==> 1
b ==> 2
c ==> 3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
new_list = [a+"==>"+b if isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, str) else str(a)+"==>"+str(b) for a, b in foo_dict.items()]

#then, just print the contents

for i in new_list:
    print i
```

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that it will error if there are keys or values that are no strings. That's not the case here, but perhaps you should add a "warning" to your answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Or simply cast `a` and `b` to strings before concatenation.

Comment: I do not really get why the ternary operator is used: `str(x) == x` if `x` is a string.